# Coefficients in Laurent expansion of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I came across the following question:
If a complex function $f(z)$ is real on the x-axis and Laurent expansion about origin is $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ has $a_n=0$ for $n<-N$, then show that the coefficients $a_n$ are real.

I attempted the solution:
I considered $z^N f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{(-N+n)}z^n$. This has no poles about the origin, hence by residue theorem, the integral over any closed contour of $z^N f(z)$ has to be zero. Now, by Morera's theorem $z^N f(z)$ is analytic and hence has the unique Laurent expansion $z^N f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{(-N+n)}z^n$. Since $f(z)$ is real when $z$ is real, we can conclude $a_n$ is real.

Is this proof correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @EricWofsey That is not mentioned in the question. Why is that relevant?

Comment: Well, it is poor form not to mention it (without specifying the domain the question is kind of meaningless).  I guess the domain is assumed to be some deleted neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes some region around the origin may be excluded. Is the structure of the proof correct?